# Activiti Model BPMN XML creation failed. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a. Signal throwing event bug?

Tags: xml, validation, activiti, bpmn

I am having troubles when I try to deploy a model. The thing is, this model has always worked but whenever I try to work with signal definitions the xml created seems to be corrupted, it gives me this exception:

Create of BPMN XML failed.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'EDITOR_RESOURCEID'. One of '{WC[##other:"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"]}' is expected.

[image: model]

I have been experiencing some bugs like whenever I try to change a Signal definition in my model, it always creates an empty signal definition in the bpmn20.xml giving me the error of an empty ID.

I don't know if this is a bug or not but it's getting a bit annoying.
I hope this is being my fault or I am missing something here.
I am using Activiti 5.18 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently it was an issue of the boundary error event, not about the signal. Once a boundary Event has a target, it gives an error if **it's not correctly attached to its task**. Sometimes boundaries can appear attached when they are not in activiti-explorer.